# Unicode module not found despite installation using Google Colab

Tags: python, installation

I've installed `unicode` on google colab

```
!pip install unicode
```

```
Requirement already satisfied: unicode in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages (2.7)
```

And I've double checked if this has worked

```
!pip show unicode
```

```
Name: unicode
Version: 2.7
Summary: Display unicode character properties
Home-page: http://kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk/~garabik/software/unicode.html
Author: Radovan Garabik
Author-email: radovan.garabik@kassiopeia.juls.savba.sk
License: GNU GPL v3
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

But when I try to `import` it, I get this error

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-15293d0741a3> in <module>()
----> 1 import unicode

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'unicode'
```

Can someone help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[unicode](https://github.com/garabik/unicode) is a command line utility, it is meant to be run in the terminal.  It is not importable in Python scripts.

You could try copying the unicode script, which is named `unicode` to `unicode.py`.  This would make it importable, but it looks to me as if it won't really be usable - it has been designed as a script, not a library.